# selectedNode=null in trees inside accordionPanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am able to display trees inside accordionPanel -one different tree in each tab of the accordionPanel-.
Problem comes when I try to catch selected node of the trees.
If I select one node of the tree in the first or second tab, I always get null in the respective selectedNode attribute.
It only takes in account if the node selected is in the tree of the last tab of the accordion

Could somebody provide some advice?

Here is the code

```
<p:accordionPanel value="${bean.menus}" var="menu">
    <p:tab title="#{menu.name}">
        <p:tree value="#{menu.tree.root}" var="node"
            rendered="#{menu.tree != null}" 
            selectionMode="single"
            selection="#{menu.tree.selectedNode}">  
            <p:treeNode>
                <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>                       
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Notes:

1. I'am using 3.2 version
2. I'am unable to display trees inside acordion with ui:repeat strategy

Thanks

Comment: I imagine this would be the same problem if instead of an `accordionPanel` component you had the `tree` inside of a `<ui:repeat>`.  What version of PrimeFaces are you using?  This might be a bug.